How can I filter helm-ag results by filename pattern?
Is there a way to interactively filter helm-ag searches by filename pattern or globbing directly within the helm-ag buffer?
I'm looking for an interactive way to specify a filename glob pattern like ".py" or "src/**/.js" and have helm-ag only search in matching files.
I guess this is relevant
https://github.com/emacsorphanage/helm-ag/issues/408
